# Change vertical menu to horizontal CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change this menu from vertical to horizontal, I'm not very familiar with css so I'm not sure about the solution. So far I understand that with the parameter display:inline-block; you can specify that the elements are arranged horizontally but it doesn't work for me. I would appreciate any help.

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
      $submenuWrapper = $('> .wrapper', $menuItem);

    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75),
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  /*width: 200px;
        max-height: 250px;overflow-y: auto;*/
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  position: static;
}

li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li .wrapper {
  cursor: auto;
}

li .wrapper li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0e8ce0;
}

li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: #0064b3;
}

.parent {
  background: #00b99b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>Abc</li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Mno >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li class="parent">
              Mno >
              <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                  <li>Abc</li>
                  <li>Def</li>
                  <li>Ghi</li>
                  <li>Jkl</li>
                  <li>Mno</li>
                  <li>Pqr</li>
                  <li>Stu</li>
                  <li>Vw</li>
                  <li>Xyz</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Abc >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li>Mno</li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li>Mno</li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there are so many options ,but for quick fix you can use css display property.
Use display: table-cell;

Comment: Try, ```display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;``` for unordered list  ```.wrapper ul```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the list to display as flex it will (by default) show its children in one row.

From there you can decide how to cope with it on narrow devices (perhaps a media query which sets the flex direction) and you can also spread the li items out in horizontal mode by looking at the various justify-content settings.

This snippet sets justify-content: spread-between just as an example.

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
      $submenuWrapper = $('> .wrapper', $menuItem);

    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75),
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  /*width: 200px;
        max-height: 250px;overflow-y: auto;*/
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.wrapper > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  position: static;
}

li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li .wrapper {
  cursor: auto;
}

li .wrapper li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0e8ce0;
}

li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: #0064b3;
}

.parent {
  background: #00b99b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>Abc</li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Mno >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li class="parent">
              Mno >
              <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                  <li>Abc</li>
                  <li>Def</li>
                  <li>Ghi</li>
                  <li>Jkl</li>
                  <li>Mno</li>
                  <li>Pqr</li>
                  <li>Stu</li>
                  <li>Vw</li>
                  <li>Xyz</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Abc >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li>Mno</li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li>Mno</li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to display the list down and not in the same row?

Comment: Yes,, as I suggested you change the flex direction. Perhaps you could describe a bit more what you want as your original code shows the list down already.

Comment: I only need the parent list horizontally and the other lists to fall off vertically, like a dropdown.With this solution all the dropdown lists are being displayed horizontally

Comment: Just be more selective on which ul gets the flex, eg select only those uls which are direct children of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Add **display:flex** it will work

```
ul {
  /*width: 200px;
        max-height: 250px;overflow-y: auto;*/
        display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the "display: inline-block" property in the li selector and it will make all the lists horizontal.

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
      $submenuWrapper = $('> .wrapper', $menuItem);

    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75),
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  /*width: 200px;
        max-height: 250px;overflow-y: auto;*/
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
}

li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;

}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li .wrapper {
  cursor: auto;
}

li .wrapper li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0e8ce0;
}

li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: #0064b3;
}

.parent {
  background: #00b99b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>Abc</li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Mno >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li class="parent">
              Mno >
              <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                  <li>Abc</li>
                  <li>Def</li>
                  <li>Ghi</li>
                  <li>Jkl</li>
                  <li>Mno</li>
                  <li>Pqr</li>
                  <li>Stu</li>
                  <li>Vw</li>
                  <li>Xyz</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
      <li class="parent">
        Abc >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Def</li>
            <li>Ghi</li>
            <li>Jkl</li>
            <li>Mno</li>
            <li>Pqr</li>
            <li>Stu</li>
            <li>Vw</li>
            <li>Xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Def</li>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li>Mno</li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Stu</li>
      <li>Vw</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```